# support for svg in qooxdoo

Tags: javascript, svg, qooxdoo

I like to load a svg into my qooxdoo gui, link some event handlers to svg elements (pointerdown, pointermove) and manipulate the svg elements from outside (style.transform=rotate). So I need access to the svg elements from the qooxdoo level. But how to embed the svg into qooxdoo not only as an image?
Is there support for handling a svg in qooxdoo?
I found a way how to embed svg in html5. Here you can embed the svg dom-structure by the tag: object. This is what I am looking for in qooxdoo.
And I found a qooxdoo svg-contrib; But this is some years old (2011) and I am wondering if it is already integrated into qooxdoo or if it is still the best starting point?

Answer (score 0):

[D3.js](https://d3js.org/) is a good module to manipulate svg objects in Javascript. However, I'm not sure whether you can integrate the module to qooxdoo framework.

Answer (score 0):

Having used snap.svg, svg.js, raphael and fabric.js for interactive as well as graphic production stuff (engineering data to PDF reports) I'm currently relying on fabric.js only, allowing for easy dynamic loading of SVG, a pretty good transition to HTML5 canvas and with that a good level of possible interaction with controls on the page. All of these libraries come with quite a learning curve, but using Inkscape as the basic SVG templating tool and fabric.js as the rendering library lets you streamline the production process quite nicely.